# WordPress $wpdb->get_results() not returning value

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm in the process of looking at a WordPress plugin (never used WordPress before) and am running into an issue trying to execute a very basic SELECT statement against the database.

Ex:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts";
$result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
var_dump($result);
echo($result);
```

This doesn't display anything even though my wp_posts table has a couple hundred rows.  Can someone tell me what I'm missing?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may or may not be the issue, but often, prefixes cause trouble and it is not recommended to hardcode tables in.

Secondly, can you output the value of `$wpdb`? If not, and this is most likely the problem, you don't have access to `$wpdb` in your scope.

Use `global $wpdb` if you are executing this within a function.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts";
$result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );
```

Comment: Looks like I didn't have access to $wpdb.  I was able to access it via $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results.  using global $wpdb fixed the issue.